# Youtube page and videos are not displaying properly

Tags: firefox, video, flash, youtube

**YouTube page is not displaying properly**

I am new user to n ubuntu just installed 15.04 a month ago. 
it was working fine till 15 days but now youtube is showing properly
i have downloaded ubuntu restricted extras, reinstalled flash player
updated the packages more than 10 times
I also  installed youtube application separetely  but still having same problem

all the other video streaming sites works well but not youtube 
[image: youtube homepage]

Comment: Visit [Adobe's flashplayer test site](https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/). You should be able to see the jumping cube animation and the version info box, if your flashplayer is installed correctly.  Please add some information to your question by [edit]ing it: What browser do you use (FireFox, Chrome,...)? Do you have any plug-ins that restrict scripts and objects (NoScript, Flashblock, Disconnect,... for Firefox)? Which flashplayer version do you have installed? Are you sure Youtube is using flash or might it be you can't display HTML5 videos?

Comment: i have the same problem in firefox, links2 and even with youtube application , i've tried both html5 and flash   player  plugins.... if flash player had a defect it shouldn't run other streaming site. right ?

Comment: @ByteBOT i have updated my browser youtube page

Comment: What you are seeing instead of the youtube homepage is probably falsely displayed because you use a script-blocker or java-script is not working, I guess. Could you update your question with a list of your installed firefox add-ons and plug-ins? Probably one of them is causing the mess or is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, if you are reading this in 2016, I turned off my adblock and it works fine now, so try that.